# marklogic encoding xdmp:document-load

Tags: encoding, utf-8, marklogic

I have noticed that utf-8 xml documents loaded (`xdmp:document-get()` + `xdmp:document-insert()`) into our development marklogic server (7.0-6.8) have ascii encoding. Meanwhile back on production server (7.0-5.1), there is no problem; utf-8 is loaded as utf-8. I traced the problem and found it to be caused by `xdmp:document-get()`.

So I wrote the following code snippet and ran it on both server consoles and got incorrect encoding on the development server and correct encoding on production.

```
let $options := <options xmlns="xdmp:document-get">
  <repair>full</repair>
  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  <format>xml</format>
</options>
let $url := "http://******/ref_batches/electronic/20170801_e31_004   /201731780-004.xml"
return xdmp:document-get($url, $options)
```

My initial guess: different version numbers may have caused this. So I tested on a local server (7.0-6-12) and got correct utf-8 encoding. Later we upgraded our development server to (7.0-6-12) and re-tested to get incorrect encoding (ascii)

Is there some marklogic configurations that are responsible for this trans-coding?

thanks

Comment: How did you test what encoding the data inside MarkLogic has?

Comment: For documents already ingested, I used fn:doc(), the <?xml> tag shows encoding attribute. The code above returns document to console output. In addition, when comparing the output of the code above on our devel server against source document, I found 117 differences. For example "September 21–24, 2016" became "September 21&#x2013;24, 2016"

Comment: I don't think that is a reliable method. Use xdmp:save to save your file to disk, and compare that with the original. And even that can be influenced by output settings of app-server, or option declarations in your code..